# Understanding the def clean(self) method inside custom login form class

Tags: python, django, forms, authentication

Django Version = 2.2.2.

Does it not make sense to take out the def clean(self) method from class LoginForm(form.ModelForm)

```
class LoginForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ['email', 'password']

    def clean(self):
        if self.is_valid():
            email = self.cleaned_data['email']
            password = self.cleaned_data['password']
            if not authenticate(email=email, password=password):
                raise forms.ValidationError('Invalid login')
```

and put it inside the view function for login:

```
def login_screen_view(request):
    context = {}
    if request.POST:
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            email = request.POST['email']
            password = request.POST['password']
            user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
            if user:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = LoginForm()

    context['login_form'] = form
    return render(request, 'account/login.html', context)
```

So that the above two blocks of code becomes now this:

```
class LoginForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ['email', 'password']


def login_screen_view(request):
    context = {}
    if request.POST:
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            email = request.POST['email']
            password = request.POST['password']
            user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
            if user:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('home')
            else:
                raise forms.ValidationError('Invalid login')    #i added this line
    else:
        form = LoginForm()

    context['login_form'] = form
    return render(request, 'account/login.html', context)
```

The reason why I say all this is because in the def clean(self) method aren't you basically checking if the form is valid? We also check if the form is valid in the view as well. So why repeat the logic? Then if we cannot authenticate the user we raise a ValidationError which I think can be added in the view definition.

Comment: _We also check if the form is valid in the view as well_ Generally the view will only call `form.is_valid()`, and all other form validation will be in the form clean methods.

Comment: It makes it more clean since the `form.is_valid()` will already check if the credentials match, in that case, one thus can immediately login.

Comment: but what is the difference between form.is_valid() (defined in the view) and self.is_valid() (defined in the def clean(self)? Seems to me they mean the same thing.